# add value to checkboxlist using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a value to a checkboxlist using javascript /jquery.The code below is my sample code

```
function getExpertise() {

          $.ajax({

           type: "POST",

           url: "Sample.asmx/GetExpertiseBySpecialization",

           data: "{sId: '" + $('#<%=ddlSpecialization.ClientID%>').val() + "'}",

                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                 dataType: "json",

                 success: function(response) {

         var expertise = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

        $('#<%=chkExpertise.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', false).removeOption(/./).addOption('-1', 'Please select expertise');


        for (var i = 0; i < expertise.length; i++) {

            var val = expertise[i].Id;

            var text = expertise[i].Expertise;

            $('#<%=chkExpertise.ClientID%>').addOption(val, text, false);

                                           }

                                       }

                                   });

                               }
```

Comment: Did you mean the ASP.NET CheckBoxList control?

Comment: Can you post the HTML and Javascript you have so far?

Comment: yes, it was a asp.net checkboxlist control

Comment: did you see this post ? http://forums.asp.net/p/1416683/3127300.aspx

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12423820/1426121) would help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source :

http://forums.asp.net/p/1416683/3127300.aspx

A CheckBoxList (or RadioButtonList for that matter) renders as a  tag with CheckBoxes and an HTML Label element in the  tags. To add items you would need to add a  and or  to the table, which I definitely would not advise you to do with JavaScript, since they would not persist server-side and would disappear if a PostBack occurred. I'd suggest you do a PostBack and add the items server-side.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
 <asp:listitem Value="1">Item 1</asp:listitem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<input type="button" onclick="addToCheckBoxListControl('Item 2', '2');" value="Add To CheckBoxList" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function addToCheckBoxListControl(textValue, valueValue)
{
 var tableRef = document.getElementById('<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>');

 var tableRow = tableRef.insertRow();
 var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell();

 var checkBoxRef = document.createElement('input');
 var labelRef = document.createElement('label');

 checkBoxRef.type = 'checkbox';
 labelRef.innerHTML = textValue;
 checkBoxRef.value = valueValue;

 tableCell.appendChild(checkBoxRef);
 tableCell.appendChild(labelRef);
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: this code works, the problem is, it should consist a default item (eg <asp:listitem Value="1">Item 1</asp:listitem> 
). Now how can I removed this default data using javascript.I want to removed this if I added already an item using javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkbox_id').attr('checked', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = 2; // it is assumed the CheckBoxList initially has 1 element (Element 1)
            function addElement() {
                var tableRef = document.getElementById('<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>');                              
                    var tableRow = tableRef.insertRow();

                var tableCell = tableRow.insertCell();

                var checkBoxRef = document.createElement('input');
                var labelRef = document.createElement('label');

                checkBoxRef.type = 'checkbox';
                labelRef.innerHTML = 'Element '+count;
                checkBoxRef.value = count;

                count++;

                tableCell.appendChild(checkBoxRef);
                tableCell.appendChild(labelRef);
            }
        </script>
```